# How to get subset of 10K MNIST images from Dataset class in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I found the following way to get mnist dataset in tensorflow:

```
def get_input_fn(dataset_split, batch_size, capacity=10000, min_after_dequeue=3000):

  def _input_fn():
    images_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        tensors=[dataset_split.images, dataset_split.labels.astype(np.int32)],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue,
        enqueue_many=True,
        num_threads=4)
    features_map = {'images': images_batch}
    return features_map, labels_batch

  return _input_fn

    data = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.mnist.load_mnist()

    train_input_fn = get_input_fn(data.train, batch_size=256)
    eval_input_fn = get_input_fn(data.validation, batch_size=5000)
```

data variable is Dataset object. 
This approach is quite unclear to me and I cannot figure out how to convert 60K dataset into 10K dataset.

When I do the following:

```
data = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.mnist.load_mnist().take(10000)
```

I get error:

```
AttributeError: 'Datasets' object has no attribute 'take'
```

But docs provide this method:
[image]

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

This function from contrib module is deprecated. You can use `tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()`. As per https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data, it returns

```
Tuple of Numpy arrays: `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)`.
```

So, in order to apply any functions to it you need to load it in a dataset object.

```
train, test = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path='mnist.npz')
dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train[0], train[1]))
dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test[0], test[1]))
```

Then you can apply shuffle, batch, take, or any map function to `dataset_train` or `dataset_test` objects

Comment: As you can see I got dataset in a different way (deprecated but working) and error clearly indicates that it is a dataset type....

Comment: As far as I understand, It's not a part of Dataset API. May I wonder why do you want to use exactly this function?